# iPhone 6 webapp shrinks on rotate with scale < 1

Tags: html, ios, scale, viewport, iphone-6

Some time ago I have made a test webapp on my iPhone 5. I used a 0.5 scale so that the UI looks sharper on the retina screen (border, etc.). This worked nice.

But now on my new iPhone 6 I see a very strange behaviour when rotating the device: on each rotate the page gets smaller and smaller until the app shows only a few pixels and is closed by iOS!

The webapp is still working normally on the iPhone 5, and on an iPhone 4. Also no problems when viewing as normal website in the browser. It's only on the iPhone 6 when opening as webapp from the home screen. I don't know anyone with a iPhone 6+ so did not test that.

I've minimized some test-code with scale 0.75 for anyone who wants to test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=500px, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=0.75, maximum-scale=0.75, minimum-scale=0.75" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
<style>
* { font-size: 20px; }
div {  float:left; clear: both; background: #ddd; border: 1px solid #333; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <br/>
  <div style='width: 100px'>100px</div>
  <div style='width: 200px'>200px</div>
  <div style='width: 300px'>300px</div>
  <div style='width: 400px'>400px</div>
</body></html>
```

I've tried anything I could think of in the viewport tag. Also tested on another iPhone 6, and with & without zoom mode.

Questions

- Is this a bug from Apple or not?
- Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: I just found that the [http://forecast.io] webapp _also_ has this issue. Open the settings screen (top left button) and rotate your iPhone 6 back and forth to see the screen shrinking.